# Instagram - Auto-follow is possible in android

Tags: android, instagram

Integrated **Instagram** to my app and get **followers**, **following** and **count** values. **Application** have separated **Instagram** account.Issues is When user login into the application using Instagram, they are **automatically follow** (auto-follow) the application (add users in followers list in app account) without any confirmation. Is it possible to make auto follow in Instagram using android?

Answer (score 0):

Just make POST request using relationship endpoint - https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/. It will be the id of the app for {user-id} param but the access token will be of the user. But you would need the "relationships" scope for this.